# In Woocommerce theme need to add custom external link

Tags: plugins, images, links

I am new in Woocommerce  plugins and i have requirements that in External/Affiliate product
there is one "Product URL"  field that is linking in to external url of "Buy now button".

Now i want that same url on product images and product name.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

External products in WooCommerce are instances of [`WC_Product_External`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/v2.0.20/classes/class-wc-product-external.php#L16) class. This class has public `get_product_url()` method which you can use to receive external URL.

So you need to get (current) product and call that method to get URL. After it you can use that URL in your template to wrap an image or something else.

```
/**
 * Your custom template
 */

global $product;

?>
<div>
    ...
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product->get_product_url() ) ?>"><img ...></a>
    ...
</div>
```